# Full paths with rsnapshot and rsync server at source side with --relative option are truncated - how to preserve full source paths?

Tags: linux, rsync, backup, rsnapshot

When using rsnapshot with following configuration:

```
#/etc/rsnapshot.conf
snapshot_root    /backup.rsnapshot/
rsync_long_args  --relative
backup   user@laptop:/home/user/test/  ./
```

a directory `/backup.rsnapshot/weekly.0/home/user/test/` is made at the destination machine.

However, if rsync server on laptop (i.e. the source machine) is used:

```
#/etc/rsnapshot.conf
snapshot_root    /backup.rsnapshot/
rsync_long_args  --relative
backup    rsync://IP_of_laptop/user/test/  ./
```

no full path is preserved but folder `/backup.rsnapshot/weekly.0/test` is made.

`/etc/rsyncd.conf` on laptop:

```
uid = 1000
gid = 1001
use chroot = no
max connections = 4
syslog facility = local5
pid file = /run/rsyncd.pid

[user]
        path = /home/user
        comment = user home folder
```

Hence my question is how to preserve the full paths using rsync server like it is preserved when the rsync server is not involved?

Comment: In the meanwhile I found an answer on a sister website: https://serverfault.com/questions/533810/rsync-in-daemon-mode-preserve-absolute-directory-structure however the only a part of the answer is correct, the one in which the root / is exported in rsyncd.conf, which is quite a security risky. The first part in this answer, making one folder export per module, does not solve the issue with path truncation.

Answer (score 0):

You can't see "into" an `rsync` server configuration. The module name is all that's exposed and you can't determine the associated path.